# Generate permutations with k fixed bits

Tags: permutation, bit, asymptotic-complexity

Suppose I have several N-bit numbers where K (1 < K < N) bits are fixed (i.e. 0 or 1). My goal is to generate all possible permutations.

Example: N = 3, K = 1 (middle bit is fixed to '0'). Then possible permutations are

```
000
001
100
101
```

Let's say I have number *X*=000 and array *fixed*={-1,0,-1} that stores information of fixed bits (-1 = bit not fixed, 0 or 1 = fixed).
Simple solution is to generate all permutations
`000,001,...,111` and loop through each one bit by bit and test whether all fixed bits have correct value (stored in *fixed*). If at least one fixed bit differs from the corresponding value in *fixed*, then this permutation is removed from the result.

This is, however, inefficient because it takes 2^N instead of 2^(N-K) permutations. Is there an algorithm or approach to this problem that needs only 2^(N-K) permutations (which are directly in the result)?

Comment: @GuyCoder oh damn I should read more carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple bit trick allows to solve this problem effectively.

Make binary masks:

**A** where all fixed bits are cleared (both fixed zeros and fixed ones!) and other bits are set

**B** where fixed ones are set

for example, `x01x` gives `A = 1001, B = 0010`

Traverse all submasks of `A` and set fixed ones with `B` before output:

```
 sm = A
 repeat:
      out = sm or B
     //use out bit combination  
      sm = (sm - 1) & A
 until (sm = 0)
```

This method generates all needed bit combinations without excessive steps